# Mongo DB Replica set Stuck at RECOVERING state

Tags: replication, mongodb, restore

We have created a replica set and now the problem is 2 members of replica set [3 members set] are in recovering mode from 48 hours. Initially the size of recovering nodes was increasing and now even that has stopped. So in recovering nodes they are stuck after 90 GB of data with 60+ GB of local data.

How to come out of this mode ?

Answer (score 15):

#### The easy, albeit a bit unsecure way

1. Stop the first secondary
2. Delete the content of it's `dbpath`
3. Restart the secondary
4. Wait for it to catch up with the primary
5. Repeat process with the second secondary

This is a bit unsecure as it is unknown why the secondaries entered the Recovering state.

#### The more secure, but also more intrusive way

As above, but stop your application during the process. This prevents the possibility that your application is inserting more data than the secondaries are able to replicate. However, the problem may occur during production.

#### The most secure, but also most intrusive way

1. Shut down the whole replica set
2. Remove the content of `dbpath` on *both* secondaries
3. Copy the content of `dbpath` to both secondaries' `dbpath`
4. Start the old primary.
5. Start one of the old secondaries.
6. Wait until a new primary is elected.
7. Start the remaining secondary.

*Some notes:*

Use [MMS](https://mms.mongodb.com/). It's free, it's easy to set up and it gives you good information about your replica set. Try to keep the value for "replication lag" around 0, and take all means necessary that your replication lag is never greater than the "replication oplog window".

Always make sure you have a 1Gb network and a (sorry) shitload of RAM. The more, the better. Additional rule of thumb: rather half the RAM and SSDs than double the RAM and no SSDs (with RAM remaining within reasonable limits).

*Disclaimer:* ***Always*** make a backup of production data before fiddling with it.

Comment: As of now we don't have a secondary node in the replica set. One is in PRIMARY mode and other two are in RECOVERING mode.

Comment: Logical secondaries, then. The process is the same.

Comment: I have tried many times starting the Mongo instance and resync, every time it starts copying the data to other node till a fixed size (~96gb) and then gets stuck. Does oplog size has to do something with it?

Comment: Not really, except for the fact that the resync might stop when you insert more data than the oplog can hold during the initial resync. Take option 2 or 3 in this case.

Comment: Can you explain this bit further?
" rather half the RAM and SSDs than double the RAM and no SSDs (with RAM remaining within reasonable limits)."

Answer (score 1):

The replication process fails even if you start scratch from a new dbpath on the secondary.So the thing is to make some **changes in the oplog**. The size of the oplog must be set to a optimal value that so that it should be able to handle all application writes into it.

**Increasing oplog size:**

Shutdown the primary server

```
use admin

db.shutdownServer()
```

Start primary as standalone & run on different port say 37017

Login to mongo in port 37017

```
mongo --port 37017
```

Remove the old contents in local database

For safety have backop of old oplog before dropping

```
mongodump --db local --collection 'oplog.rs' --port 37017
```

Drop the old contents in local database

```
use local

db.oplog.rs.drop()

db.me.drop()

db.replset.election.drop()

db.replset.minvalid.drop()

db.startup_log.drop()
```

Replset collection cannot be dropped so remove it with required id :

```
db.system.replset.remove({ "_id" : "your_replsetname"})
```

Create a new oplog of required size say 50 GB

```
db.runCommand( { create: "oplog.rs", capped: true, size: (50 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024) } )
```

Also you can specify the oplog size in MB in mongod.conf file,say for 50 GB its 429496 MB

```
replication:
   oplogSizeMB: 429496
```

Hope this Helps !!!

**Edit:**

As mentioned by Nicholas Tolley Cottrell in comments. In the MongoDB **version 3.6** we can change oplog size in runtime without restart.

**Check current oplog size**

```
use local
db.oplog.rs.stats().maxSize
```

**To change the oplog size to 10 GB**

```
db.adminCommand({replSetResizeOplog: 1, size: 10000})
```

Comment: The above is out of date as of 3.6. You can now resize the oplog without dropping content or even restarting nodes: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/change-oplog-size/

Comment: @NicholasTolleyCottrell yeah, I have edited the answer.